# MySQL query giving different outputs when executed in command line and Java

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have query that calculates ranks of students in a table **stu_marks** and the names of the students are in table **stu_details**. 
In stu_marks table I have `rollNo`, `exam`, `percentage` and `rank` columns and in the stu_details I have `rollNo`, `name` and `class`. I have many other columns which are not required for this query.

```
+--------+-------------------------+
| rollNo | name                    |
+--------+-------------------------+
| 361601 | ABHISHEK N D            |
| 361635 | SAI CHANDAN K           |
| 361642 | SAIPRASANNA GURUMOORTHY |
+--------+-------------------------+
```

Now I am trying to calculate ranks of students each class at a time for an exam. Ranks will be skipped if more than one student gets same percentage.

The query which I use for that is

```
set @rnk=0;  set @rank=0;  set @curScore = 0;
update stu_marks sm join
  (SELECT A.*, (@rnk:=@rnk+1) rnk, 
          (@rank:=IF(@curscore=percentage,@rank,@rnk)) rank, 
          (@curscore:=percentage) newscore from 
          (select sm1.rollNo, name, percentage, exam from stu_marks 
             sm1 join stu_details sd1  where sd1.rollNo=sm1.rollNo and 
             class='X' and exam='HalfYearly' order by percentage desc) A
  ) AA set sm.rank = AA.rank where sm.rollNo=AA.rollNo and sm.exam=AA.exam;
```

This query works fine and I am getting proper output, i.e., the ranks are getting updated properly. After executing the query stu_marks table looks like this.

```
+--------+------------------------+------+
| rollNo |    exam    |percentage | rank |
+--------+------------+-----------+------|
| 361642 | HalfYearly |   97.75   |    1 |
| 361601 | HalfYearly |   97.25   |    2 |
| 361635 | HalfYearly |   97.25   |    2 |
```

But when I run same query form Java using `PreparedStatement` it is not working.

```
        ps.executeUpdate("SET @rnk=0");
        ps.executeUpdate("SET @rank=0");
        ps.executeUpdate("SET @curPer=0");

String calculateRank = "update stu_marks sm join"
                    + "(SELECT A.*, (@rnk:=@rnk+1) rnk, (@rank:=IF(@curscore=percentage,@rank,@rnk)) rank, "
                    + "(@curscore:=percentage) newscore from "
                    + "     (select sm1.rollNo, name, percentage, exam "
                    + "     from stu_marks sm1 join stu_details sd1  "
                    + "     where sd1.rollNo=sm1.rollNo and class=? and exam=? "
                    + "     order by percentage desc) A) AA "
                    + "set sm.rank = AA.rank where sm.rollNo=AA.rollNo and sm.exam=AA.exam;";

        ps = con.prepareStatement(calculateRank);
        ps.setString(1, chosenClass);
        ps.setString(2, chosenExam);
        System.out.println(ps);
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

In this case ranks are not getting updated properly. As you can see 97.25 gets 2nd rank once and 3rd rank once.

```
+--------+------------------------+------+
| rollNo |    exam    |percentage | rank |
+--------+------------+-----------+------|
| 361642 | HalfYearly |   97.75   |    1 |
| 361601 | HalfYearly |   97.25   |    2 |
| 361635 | HalfYearly |   97.25   |    3 |
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You forgetten to set the `set @rnk=0;  set @rank=0;  set @curScore = 0;`.. i assume java's prepareStatement does not support multiple SQL statements separated by semicon so you need to execute the set's separated  .. Or you need to rewrite the update query that you init the MySQL user variables in the query itself something like `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk=0 [,...]) AS init_user_params`

Comment: I did that in the code. I didn't write it in the post. I will edit the question

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Likely the problem is that you did not disable auto-commit, or maybe you should enable connection property `allowMultiQueries` and execute in a single `execute(..)`

Comment: I am not executing multiple queries at a time. I have three variable initialization separately and then a single query that updates  the ranks and yes, disabling auto-commit, it worked.

Comment: I have not disabled auto-commit even in command line, but it worked there. Also, I am using only percentage to find the ranks which is unchanged while calculating queries. Why I need to disable auto commit from Java?